# Как исправить ошибку php?

Tags: php

Появилась такая ошибка:

```
2019-08-26 22:16:43 - PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: recommend_visit in /var/www/data/www/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_view_theme_default_template_product_product.tpl on line 286
```

286 строка:

```
<?php if($recommend_visit) { ?>
```

Пробовал так, не помогло:

```
<?php $recommend_visit = Array(); ?>
<?php if($recommend_visit) { ?>
```

Как ее исправить?

**Пример блока использования:**

```
<?php 
if($recommend_visit) { ?> 
    <p style="width: 385px;font-size: 10px;">
        * реальные цвета могут отличаться от изображенных на сайте в зависимости от настроек Вашего монитора или мобильного устройства
    </p>
    <h4>Предлагаем посетить эти разделы:</h4> 
    <ul id="recommend-visit"> 
    <?php foreach($recommend_visit as $category) { ?> 
        <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li> 
    <?php } ?> 
    </ul> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Переменная встречается только в одном месте? Просмотрите всё её время жизни от объявления.

Comment: <?php if($recommend_visit) { ?>
        <p style="width: 385px;font-size: 10px;">* реальные цвета могут отличаться от изображенных на сайте в зависимости от настроек Вашего монитора или мобильного устройства</p>
    <h4>Предлагаем посетить эти разделы:</h4>
    <ul id="recommend-visit">
      <?php foreach($recommend_visit as $category) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
  <?php } ?>

Comment: только здесь встречается

Answer (score 0):

Используйте проверку на существование, она у вас раньше определяется с каким-либо условием, скорее всего выполнение кода не зашло в условную конструкцию, где будет объявлена данная переменная, или же не был подключен соответствующий файл, где она существует в **глобальной** видимости (не путайте с `global`)

```
<?php if($recommend_visit ?: null) { ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте в той же секции php делать.

```
<?php 
$recommend_visit = []; 
if($recommend_visit) { ?>
```

Проблема в том, что переменной такой нет. Возможно она объявляется в файле, который вы не подключили. Возможно конструкция `global $recommend_visit` может помочь.

Вообще можете запустить дебагер и узнать какие переменные есть в конкретный момент времени.

Comment: В той же секции если делать, то блок рекомендаций не отображается, так же как и в моем способе

Comment: Попробуй сделать не пустым. Проверка такая не пройдет. Тебе надо сделать ее хоть каким-то значением

Comment: Спасибо! А можно пример?

Comment: `$recommend_visit = 1; $recommend_visit = 'yes';`

Comment: вот так? 
<?php
        $recommend_visit = 1; $recommend_visit = 'yes;'
        if($recommend_visit) { ?>

Comment: У вас эта переменная, видимо, должна как-то сама появиться. Если вы сделаете одним из предложенным способом, то блок будет всегда виден.

Comment: Ничего страшного

Comment: А если вот так?
<?php if(isset ($recommend_visit)) { ?>

Comment: Нет, страшное есть. Блок станет виден всегда, вне зависимости от настроек. Вам всётаки нужно поискать что это за переменная, откуда она берётся. К тому же notice это не ошибка, а так, "когда будет время - обратите внимание". Многие разработчики не обращают на них внимания (к сожалению) и вообще запрещают вывод предупреждений в лог. так что вполне вероятно что этот nitice - ожидаемое поведение.

Comment: Вот я нашел в контроллере. Оно?
if($product_info['recommend_visit']) {
    $recommend_visit = $this->model_catalog_product->getRecommendCategories($product_info['recommend_visit']);

    foreach($recommend_visit as $category) {
     $this->data['recommend_visit'][] = array(
      'name' => $category['name'],
      'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id']),
     );
    }
   } else {
    $this->data['recommend_visit'] = array();
   }